# Microsoft Cloud App Security (MCAS) Session Policy bypassed by App but is applied/effective in Browser? "bypass session control"

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, access-control

I have the following access policy configured that should blocks access to Microsoft Teams, if there is no valid client certificate:

[image]

This policy works in the browser, when `teams.microsoft.com` is opened (including logging in with valid crendetials) with the custom error message:

[image]

**Yet, while using the Teams Desktop App, the affected user can login and use teams even without the certificate. The message in the Activity Log of Microsoft Cloud App Security states "bypass session control".**

[image]

How does the rule not affect the Teams App but work in the browser.

The teams app cannot have access to a certificate, because I tried it in a Sandbox.
As well as the bypass info must mean, somewhere a bypass is allowed/configured? But where would I find that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you extend the policy to also check the Client App both for Browser and App, then also the Teams App will be blocked by the policy (or not if the certificate is available).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

•   You are able to access Teams client app on desktop because you have not selected filters that include ‘client app equals to Mobile and Desktop’ in Access Control Policy as below.

[image: Filters in Access Control Policy]

•   So, once you select the filters as per your convenience, as above, and the actions to take as ‘block’ or ‘test’, the desktop teams will not be able to start up. Also, the ‘bypass session control’ message in the browser while accessing a blocked or restricted site is displayed in activity logs in Microsoft cloud app security because you might be having ‘admin’ level access to modify, create or delete any access control or session control policy in there.

Please find the below links for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-app-security/manage-admins

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-app-security/troubleshooting-proxy